# awk line search and word replacement not working properly

Tags: awk

```
$ cat test.txt
#Instance|job_or_Box_name|Status | to_be_checked_for_T_or_F|Time_to_check|DaysTo_be_checked|Timezone |already_checked|Mail mesasge
P51|EAMDEUEQTTAQPOSTRTSAVE_Box|SU|T|0500|12345|BST|N|MDS price for pcb 
P51|EAMDEUEQTTAQPOSTRTSAVE_Box|SU|T|0600|123|BST|N| BW RTB Enterprise Services
```

I want to get output like

```
#Instance|job_or_Box_name|Status | to_be_checked_for_T_or_F|Time_to_check|DaysTo_be_checked|Timezone |already_checked|Mail mesasge
P51|EAMDEUEQTTAQPOSTRTSAVE_Box|SU|T|0500|12345|BST|Y|MDS price for pcb 
P51|EAMDEUEQTTAQPOSTRTSAVE_Box|SU|T|0600|123|BST|N|BW RTB Enterprise Services
```

There is a change in second line (variable) and 8th field. I tried:

```
v="2"
line="P51|EAMDEUEQTTAQPOSTRTSAVE_Box|SU|T|0500|12345|BST|Y|MDS price for pcb"
awk -v v=$v -v v2=$line 'BEGIN { FS="|" ; OFS="|" }  $0 ~ v2 {$8 = "Y" ; print $0 }'  test.txt
```

But it doesn't work properly and converts 8th column for every line.
Also tried

```
awk -v v=$v -v v2=$line 'BEGIN { FS="|" ; OFS="|" }  /v2/ {$8 = "Y" ; print $0 }'  test.txt
```

but doesn't work ..

Comment: if you need to change 8th field of 2nd line, `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} NR==2{$8="Y"} 1' test.txt` will do... you've defined variable `v="2"` but not used.. did you mean to use that to indicate 2nd line?

Comment: Many thanks buddy.small modification is required to suppress line printing twice.#Instance|job_or_Box_name|Status | to_be_checked_for_T_or_F|Time_to_check|DaysTo_be_checked|Timezone |already_checked|Mail mesasge
P51|EAMDEUEQTTAQPOSTRTSAVE_Box|SU|T|0500|12345|BST|Y|Services team
P51|EAMDEUEQTTAQPOSTRTSAVE_Box|SU|T|0500|12345|BST|Y|Services team
P51|EAMDEUEQTTAQPOSTRTSAVE_Box|SU|F|3500|125|BST|N|MDS price for pcb

Answer (score 0):

try

```
LINE="P51|EAMDEUEQTTAQPOSTRTSAVE_Box|SU|T|0500|12345|BST|N|"
awk -v v2="$line" 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }  index($0,v2) {$8 = "Y" ; } {print;}' file.txt
```

where

- `index($0,v2)` will search whole line field on line (can be replace by `NR==v` if you prefer line number searching)
- when a match is found `$8` is changed,
- next pattern print fields

Comment: Many thanks; Exactly what i wanted. I spoiled whole day to figure out the issue.